# Populate Android SQLite Dat Records into Excel

Tags: android, android-activity

I create my Project . but I sucked in final mode.. My Table has been generated but for attaching Purpose, I have to create that Table into EXCEL.. PLease give me link. I also tried for pdf but API is not free for commercial use. so give me guide lines , links or GitHub...

Comment: http://androidamaranthine.blogspot.in/2013/01/export-sqlite-to-excel.html

Comment: dear Fahim, Thnxx a lot for quick response but I have to perform this task programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to convert the sqlite database into csv then convert the csv file to xls.You will need 2 libraries (opencsv-1.7.jar poi-3.8-20120326.jar)

```
 public class ExportDatabaseCSVTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>

{
private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(DatabaseExampleActivity.this);

 @Override

protected void onPreExecute()

{

    this.dialog.setMessage("Exporting database...");

    this.dialog.show();

}



protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args)

{


    File dbFile=getDatabasePath("database_name");
    //AABDatabaseManager dbhelper = new AABDatabaseManager(getApplicationContext());
    AABDatabaseManager dbhelper = new AABDatabaseManager(DatabaseExampleActivity.this) ;
    System.out.println(dbFile);  // displays the data base path in your logcat 


    File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");        

    if (!exportDir.exists()) 

    {
        exportDir.mkdirs();
    }


    File file = new File(exportDir, "excerDB.csv");


    try

    {

        if (file.createNewFile()){
            System.out.println("File is created!");
            System.out.println("myfile.csv "+file.getAbsolutePath());
          }else{
            System.out.println("File already exists.");
          }

        CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
      //SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor curCSV=db.getdb().rawQuery("select * from " + db.TABLE_NAME,null);

        csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());

        while(curCSV.moveToNext())

        {

            String arrStr[] ={curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1),curCSV.getString(2)};

         /*curCSV.getString(3),curCSV.getString(4)};*/

            csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);


        }

        csvWrite.close();
        curCSV.close();
        /*String data="";
        data=readSavedData();
        data= data.replace(",", ";");
        writeData(data);*/

        return true;

    }

    catch(SQLException sqlEx)

    {

        Log.e("MainActivity", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);

        return false;

    }

    catch (IOException e)

    {

        Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);

        return false;

    }

}

protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success)

{

    if (this.dialog.isShowing())

    {

        this.dialog.dismiss();

    }

    if (success)

    {

        Toast.makeText(DatabaseExampleActivity.this, "Export succeed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    else

    {

        Toast.makeText(DatabaseExampleActivity.this, "Export failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}}
```

Export CSV to XLS part

```
public class CSVToExcelConverter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {


private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(DatabaseExampleActivity.this);

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{this.dialog.setMessage("Exporting to excel...");
 this.dialog.show();}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    ArrayList arList=null;
    ArrayList al=null;

    //File dbFile= new File(getDatabasePath("database_name").toString());
    File dbFile=getDatabasePath("database_name");
    String yes= dbFile.getAbsolutePath();

    String inFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/excerDB.csv";
    outFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/test.xls";
    String thisLine;
    int count=0;

    try {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inFilePath);
    DataInputStream myInput = new DataInputStream(fis);
    int i=0;
    arList = new ArrayList();
    while ((thisLine = myInput.readLine()) != null)
    {
    al = new ArrayList();
    String strar[] = thisLine.split(",");
    for(int j=0;j<strar.length;j++)
    {
    al.add(strar[j]);
    }
    arList.add(al);
    System.out.println();
    i++;
    }} catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("shit");
    }

    try
    {
    HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("new sheet");
    for(int k=0;k<arList.size();k++)
    {
    ArrayList ardata = (ArrayList)arList.get(k);
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) 0+k);
    for(int p=0;p<ardata.size();p++)
    {
    HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) p);
    String data = ardata.get(p).toString();
    if(data.startsWith("=")){
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
    data=data.replaceAll("=", "");
    cell.setCellValue(data);
    }else if(data.startsWith("\"")){
    data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    cell.setCellValue(data);
    }else{
    data=data.replaceAll("\"", "");
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
    cell.setCellValue(data);
    }
    //*/
    // cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(p).toString());
    }
    System.out.println();
    }
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outFilePath);
    hwb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated");
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    } //main method ends
    return true;
}

protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success)

{

    if (this.dialog.isShowing())

    {

        this.dialog.dismiss();

    }

    if (success)

    {

        Toast.makeText(DatabaseExampleActivity.this, "file is built!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    else

    {

        Toast.makeText(DatabaseExampleActivity.this, "file fail to build", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}


}
```

Comment: Hi BKS..... thnxx a lot dear.... Is there any way to take screenshot of particular screen in android then convrt that image to pdf ? By the way, Thank you so much for such type help...

Comment: Yes. Taking screenshots is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android and you can use AndroidPDFViewerLibrary-master library for converting image to pdf.Thanks.

Comment: in my code, where I should paste this code BKS.... I am pasting but its showing me error.. I am new in android